# Focus elements by keyboard shortcuts in AngularJS (cross-browser solution)

Tags: html, angularjs

Does anybody can advice for a good angular directive that can focus on web elements using keyboard shortcuts. something like accessKey attribute in HTML5 (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_accesskey.asp), but more flexible.

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by "more flexible". You can always put an interpolated expression in the attribute value and if that doesn't do it for you, creating a directive that changes attribute value based on your needs should be [trivial](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

Comment: More flexible means I don't want to depend on browser accessing shortcut key.

Comment: Why? The site you linked suggests that all modern browsers support this functionality.

Comment: As you can see not all browser have the same accessing shortcut key, I want to use the same shortcuts in all browsers.